# query multiple database connections with sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-schema, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have 2 database in ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER connections, con1 and con2 (with different schemas)

I need to create a view, based on columns from both db's , the method:

```
Create VIEW testviewAS (SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM con1.table1);
ALTER VIEW AS (SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM con2.table2);
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: creating a view is nothing to do with connections in SQL developer. Connect in one session with sufficient authority and schema qualify the table names.

Comment: You mean I won't be able to create that view?

Comment: what does `con1.table1` mean? is your schema called `con1`?

Comment: yes , it's called as its connection in SQL Developer

Comment: then I suggest you call it something else—reading the Oracle Concepts guide about schemas may make things clearer here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/intro.htm#autoId5.

Comment: Already read, I do understand difference , but thank you anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this solution

in the second connection worksheet I access grants on table2 to conection1 one

```
GRANT SELECT on table2 to Connection1
```

and then I create view (on the 1sr connection worksheet):

```
Create VIEW testview AS (SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM con1.table1);
ALTER VIEW AS (SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM con2.table2);
```

Comment: but in this solution you have data only from table2 in your view.

Comment: yes, that's what I needed, you always can grant select on other tables from connection2

Answer (score 0):

Did you intend to do a union of two tables on different schemas?

```
Create VIEW testviewAS (
    SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3, t2.col1, t2.col2, t2.col3 FROM con1.table1 t1, con2.table2 t2 where t1.col1 = t2.col1
);
```

Comment: I meant join tables by one column